# Creating a list of leaves recursively in a binary tree java

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

My recursive function to count number of leaves in a Binary Tree works correctly:

```
public static int numberOfLeaves(BinaryTree<String> root) {

    if (root == null) return 0;
    else if(root.isLeaf()) return 1;
    int left = numberOfLeaves(root.leftTree);
    int right = numberOfLeaves(root.rightTree);
    return (left + right);
}
```

But now I want to sum up the data of all the leaves in a `List` and **return** it.

Have a look at my hopeless attempt:

```
public ArrayList<String> getDataLeaves(BinaryTree<String> root) {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    if (root == null) return list;
    else if (root.isLeaf()) list.add(root.data);
    else if(root.leftTree != null ) getDataLeaves(root.leftTree);
    else getDataLeaves(root.rightTree);

    return list;
}
```

Can I (how do I) use the functionality/style of my *numberOfLeaves* function to help me write a **recursive** function which will sum up the data of all the leaves in a **list** and **return** it.

Note:
a **node** is of type `BinaryTree<String>`
with `data`, `leftTree`,`RightTree` as instance variables.

Comment: This should be easy stuff for someone who is good with recursion, my brain isn't used to recursion enough to help myself.. Thnx in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the leaves returned by the recursive calls:

```
public ArrayList<String> getDataLeaves(BinaryTree<String> root) {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    if (root == null) 
        return list;
    else if (root.isLeaf()) 
        list.add(root.data);
    else { 
        list.addAll(getDataLeaves(root.leftTree));
        list.addAll(getDataLeaves(root.rightTree));
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: I want to do for example a pre order traversal accross the tree and if the node is a leaf, add it to the list. The example of my attempt doesn't really do that I think, so this addition to my code won't work  (it doesn't work, it returns in my tree of 9 nodes only 1 node).

Comment: @coders It should only return the leaf nodes. How many leaf nodes are in your tree?

Comment: 4 leaf nodes in a Binary tree of 9 nodes @Eran

Comment: @coders are you sure your `isLeaf` method is implemented correctly?

Comment: yess that was missing, the calls needed to be added after one other. It works now thanks